# nusoap wsdl connection error but in telnet test everything is OK

Tags: php, configuration, wsdl, connection, nusoap

I use nusoap to connect to an URL,
But I cannot connect and I didn't get any error in `$soapclient->getError()` .

I can connect to that URL via SSH commant and telnet, that URL show an XML data on browser and everything seems to be OK but PHP cannot connect!

I think I have problem in `php.ini` configuration !
can you help me to solve this problem ?

when I trying to `echo $soapclient;` I get content :

```
object(nusoap_client)#25 (50) {
  ["username"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["password"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["authtype"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["certRequest"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["requestHeaders"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["responseHeaders"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["responseHeader"]=>
  NULL
  ["document"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["endpoint"]=>
  string(60) "https://******?wsdl"
  ["forceEndpoint"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["proxyhost"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["proxyport"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["proxyusername"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["proxypassword"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["portName"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["xml_encoding"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["http_encoding"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["timeout"]=>
  int(0)
  ["response_timeout"]=>
  int(30)
  ["endpointType"]=>
  string(4) "wsdl"
  ["persistentConnection"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["defaultRpcParams"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["request"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["response"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["responseData"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["cookies"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["decode_utf8"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["operations"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["curl_options"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["bindingType"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["use_curl"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["fault"]=>
  NULL
  ["faultcode"]=>
  NULL
  ["faultstring"]=>
  NULL
  ["faultdetail"]=>
  NULL
  ["title"]=>
  string(6) "NuSOAP"
  ["version"]=>
  string(5) "0.9.5"
  ["revision"]=>
  string(18) "$Revision: 1.123 $"
  ["error_str"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["debug_str"]=>
  string(311) "2013-05-13 10:35:52.670129 nusoap_client: ctor wsdl=wsdl timeout=0 response_timeout=30
endpoint=string(60) "https://******?wsdl"
2013-05-13 10:35:52.670242 nusoap_client: will use lazy evaluation of wsdl from https://******?wsdl
"
  ["charencoding"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["debugLevel"]=>
  int(9)
  ["XMLSchemaVersion"]=>
  string(32) "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  ["soap_defencoding"]=>
  string(10) "ISO-8859-1"
  ["namespaces"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["SOAP-ENV"]=>
    string(41) "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    ["xsd"]=>
    string(32) "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    ["xsi"]=>
    string(41) "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    ["SOAP-ENC"]=>
    string(41) "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
  }
  ["usedNamespaces"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["typemap"]=>
  array(6) {
    ["http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"]=>
    array(43) {
      ["string"]=>
      string(6) "string"
      ["boolean"]=>
      string(7) "boolean"
      ["float"]=>
      string(6) "double"
      ["double"]=>
      string(6) "double"
      ["decimal"]=>
      string(6) "double"
      ["duration"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["dateTime"]=>
      string(6) "string"
      ["time"]=>
      string(6) "string"
      ["date"]=>
      string(6) "string"
      ["gYearMonth"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["gYear"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["gMonthDay"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["gDay"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["gMonth"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["hexBinary"]=>
      string(6) "string"
      ["base64Binary"]=>
      string(6) "string"
      ["anyType"]=>
      string(6) "string"
      ["anySimpleType"]=>
      string(6) "string"
      ["normalizedString"]=>
      string(6) "string"
      ["token"]=>
      string(6) "string"
      ["language"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["NMTOKEN"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["NMTOKENS"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["Name"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["NCName"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["ID"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["IDREF"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["IDREFS"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["ENTITY"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["ENTITIES"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["integer"]=>
      string(7) "integer"
      ["nonPositiveInteger"]=>
      string(7) "integer"
      ["negativeInteger"]=>
      string(7) "integer"
      ["long"]=>
      string(7) "integer"
      ["int"]=>
      string(7) "integer"
      ["short"]=>
      string(7) "integer"
      ["byte"]=>
      string(7) "integer"
      ["nonNegativeInteger"]=>
      string(7) "integer"
      ["unsignedLong"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["unsignedInt"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["unsignedShort"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["unsignedByte"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["positiveInteger"]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
    ["http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema"]=>
    array(11) {
      ["i4"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["int"]=>
      string(7) "integer"
      ["boolean"]=>
      string(7) "boolean"
      ["string"]=>
      string(6) "string"
      ["double"]=>
      string(6) "double"
      ["float"]=>
      string(6) "double"
      ["dateTime"]=>
      string(6) "string"
      ["timeInstant"]=>
      string(6) "string"
      ["base64Binary"]=>
      string(6) "string"
      ["base64"]=>
      string(6) "string"
      ["ur-type"]=>
      string(5) "array"
    }
    ["http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema"]=>
    array(11) {
      ["i4"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["int"]=>
      string(7) "integer"
      ["boolean"]=>
      string(7) "boolean"
      ["string"]=>
      string(6) "string"
      ["double"]=>
      string(6) "double"
      ["float"]=>
      string(6) "double"
      ["dateTime"]=>
      string(6) "string"
      ["timeInstant"]=>
      string(6) "string"
      ["base64Binary"]=>
      string(6) "string"
      ["base64"]=>
      string(6) "string"
      ["ur-type"]=>
      string(5) "array"
    }
    ["http://soapinterop.org/xsd"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["SOAPStruct"]=>
      string(6) "struct"
    }
    ["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["base64"]=>
      string(6) "string"
      ["array"]=>
      string(5) "array"
      ["Array"]=>
      string(5) "array"
    }
    ["http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(3) "Map"
    }
  }
  ["xmlEntities"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["quot"]=>
    string(1) """
    ["amp"]=>
    string(1) "&"
    ["lt"]=>
    string(1) "<"
    ["gt"]=>
    string(1) ">"
    ["apos"]=>
    string(1) "'"
  }
  ["wsdlFile"]=>
  string(60) "https://******?wsdl"
  ["wsdl"]=>
  NULL
}
```

this is my code :

```
require_once('libs/nusoap/nusoap.php');
$soapclient = new nusoap_client('https://*****?wsdl','wsdl');
echo $soapclient->getError() ;
echo $soapclient;
```

Comment: What about authorization parameters, should't be in request?

Comment: We didn't need authorization in this step